# Order Information is not showing up on /sales/order/view/

Tags: magento2

I'm not sure why but my order information wrapped in `page-title-wrapper` div is not showing up on page `/sales/order/view/`. I'm talking about the content in the red border in the screenshot below.

Here is my sales_order_view.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <update handle="sales_order_item_renderers"/>
    <update handle="sales_order_item_price"/>
    <update handle="sales_order_info_links"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.title">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info" name="order.status" template="Magento_Sales::order/order_status.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info" name="order.date" template="Magento_Sales::order/order_date.phtml"/>
            <container name="order.actions.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="actions-toolbar order-actions-toolbar">
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info\Buttons" as="buttons" name="sales.order.info.buttons" cacheable="false"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="sales.order.info.buttons">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info\Buttons\Rss" as="buttons.rss" name="sales.order.info.buttons.rss" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="sales.order.info" destination="content" after="order.comments" />
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\View" name="order.comments" template="Magento_Sales::order/order_comments.phtml" before="sales.order.info.links"/>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\View" name="sales.order.view" cacheable="false" after="sales.order.info.links">
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Items" name="order_items" template="Magento_Sales::order/items.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="sales.order.items.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="sales_order_item_pager"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" name="order_totals" template="Magento_Sales::order/totals.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label_properties" xsi:type="string">colspan="4" class="mark"</argument>
                            <argument name="value_properties" xsi:type="string">class="amount"</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <block class="Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax" name="tax" template="Magento_Tax::order/tax.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
            <!-- <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info" as="info" name="sales.order.info" after="sales.order.view"/> -->
        </referenceContainer>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional.product.info" template="Magento_Theme::template.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

The file is as it is. I didn't do anything to hide or unhide that stuff. Are there any settings to enable that?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is additional content within the `page-title-wrapper` div, aside from what is already shown in your code and screenshot. I have attached a screenshot of a Magento vanilla installation with sample data as evidence.

[image: Sale order view]

Comment: I know but it its not showing up on my custom theme.

Comment: Your `sales_order_view.xml file` file is fine. The `page-title-wrapper` div is located in the `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml` file. This `phtml` template is assigned to the `page.main.title` block, which is declared in the `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` file. Therefore, you can search for `page.main.title` in the entire project code to identify which code modifies that block. You can use this command: `grep -rn "page.main.title" app vendor --exclude-dir=vendor/magento`